# COUNTIF on a manual array list

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

If I perform simple formulas such as sum() or count(), I can make it work with a manual array list, such as this...

```
=SUM({1;2;2;2;3})
```

However, when I do something like the below, it does not work.

```
=SUMIF({1;2;2;2;3}, 2, {1;2;2;2;3})
```

Does anyone know how to make something like this work, or know an alternative.

In reality, I use a fixed range, typed in a separate worksheet, in a particular formula, and my boss wants me to avoid having that extra worksheet. Hence, I was thinking of typing out the list in a single formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simulate the SUMIF using a SUM with multiplication:-

```
=SUM({1,2,2,2,3} *({1,2,2,2,3}=2))
```

or

```
=SUM({1;2;2;2;3} *({1;2;2;2;3}=2))
```

This has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can also use SUMPRODUCT if you prefer to avoid a CSE formula:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1,2,2,2,3} *({1,2,2,2,3}=2))
```